# Is the category of toposes cocomplete ?

Tags: topos-theory, limits-and-colimits

Hello.

[Edits between brackets.]

Does the [1-]category of [elementary] toposes [with logical morphisms] admit any [1-]colimits ?

[By colimit I mean initial object in the category of outgoing cocones. I'm afraid I don't know what pseudo-colimits, bicolimits or strict 2-limits are, but I can say that I'm not interested by any 2-categorical aspect of my question (at least, for now), just by the 1-categorical one.]

Any reference would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for any answer and please forgive me for my pityful english.

Comment: you said you mean elementary toposes, but which 1-cells: geometric morphisms? logical? and, which type of colimits: pseudo-colimits? bicolimits? strict 2-limits?

Comment: Logical morphisms preserve logic, so the coproduct of a topos that satisfies some proposition $p$ with another topos that satisfies $\neg p$ would have to satisfy $p\land \neg p$.

Answer (score 5):

$\mathbf{Log}$, the category of elementary topoi and logical morphisms *which preserve everything on the nose* is cocomplete; in

> Eduardo J Dubuc, GM Kelly - *A presentation of topoi as algebraic relative to categories or graphs* - Journal of Algebra ([website](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869383901977))

this category $\mathbf{Log}$ is shown to be the category of algebras of a finitary monad on $\mathbf{Cat}$; it looks like you can even get this over $\mathbf{Grph}$, like the presentation of cartesian closed categories monadic over graphs in Lambek-Scott intro to higher-order categorical logic. This implies then that it is cocomplete, see the nLab page on [colimits in categories of algebras](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/colimits+in+categories+of+algebras), for example.

For the sake of completeness, a nice account (including explicit constructions) of 2-limits in $\mathbf{Log}$ as a locally groupoidal 2-category (1-cells the standard notion of logical morphism, 2-cells between them restricted to be isomorphisms) is given in chapter III of Steve Awodey's PhD thesis,

> S Awodey - *Logic in topoi: functorial semantics for higher-order logic* - available from his [website](http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/awodey/)

Answer (score 2):

You should consult section B3 Of the Elephant by Johnstone.  My understanding is that the 2-category of Grothendieck toposes (over sets) has all small colimits. This holds more generally for bounded toposes over a topos with natural numbers object.

Comment: Just to make things clear: I presume that you are talking about 2-colimits.

Comment: Yes, I that is what I was trying to get at when I said the 2-category of Grothendieck toposes.  

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry I haven't said I was talking about 1-colimits.